# How to interpret 休息不了多长时间吧？

Tags: meaning

他是‘业余作家‘。

您在白天应酬、工作之后，晚上是怎样进入写作状态的，您晚上休息不了多长时间吧？

Have  I got this right, seems she is asking the question in reverse.

您晚上休息不了多长时间吧？ = How long do you sleep at night?

His answer is '我大概一天睡四到五个小时。‘ but her question says 'how long can't(不了） you rest'.

Answer (score 7):

您晚上休息不了多长时间吧 is between interrogative and rhetorical. It means

> (I reckon that) you don't have much time for sleep at night, do you?

There is a strong suggestion for the answer, yet an answer is expected to complete the dialog.

Word by word translation is like

> You are unable to rest for long time at night right?

Answer (score 1):

实际上，仅仅翻译一个意思即可，譬如：

You have only little time to have a test, do you?

这句话在中文中的意思是略带否定含义的，问话者的态度表明那个人几乎没有时间休息。